# Can I send a post without a form?

Tags: javascript, html, security

I'm studying web security. 
Form Security During studying, I wonder questions.

Can I send a post without a form? 
It does not ask to transfer data to the server without post transmission. 
When I send a 'post', I ask if I should go through the 'form'.

Comment: yes you can POST a request without a form

Answer (score 1):

You can use `XMLHttpRequest` to send requests of all types (**POST**, **GET**, ...)

More information [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest).

Comment: Thank you for answer. I have more questions. Except for ajax, is it possible to send a post without form using an external program?

Comment: Externall program, like a program written in another language (such as C or Java ...)?

Comment: You can send post request more or less from anywhere. You can easely write a Java application that send POST request to a server. Same for all other languages.

Answer (score 0):

POSTing in HTML without a `FORM` didn't work in the browsers I tried it in. Since the `FORM` element specifies the URL to access, there isn't really complete basis to perform such an operation.

However using `curl` or a custom HTTP client, it is definitely possible to construct & send handcrafted requests (POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, others) to an HTTP server. These are independent of any HTML pages the server might offer -- the client need never perform a GET -- and can be constructed completely arbitrarily.

For example, a request may specify parameters (eg "order.total", "customer.id", "developmentMode=true") which the web application never offered in the HTML or expected to be received. This can be a potential security hole if eg. automatic binding frameworks are used, and bindable fields should be carefully controlled when using such.

Applications must be robust against such requests as a basic principle of web security.

Answer (score 0):

Google Chrome has an extension called "Postman" that allows sending HTTP POST requests: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en